# Dynamically send blobs from azure storage account to email using azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have files getting stored in my Azure Blob storage account regularly. I want to send these blob file contents as attachments via email. I have established a workflow using Azure Logic Apps.

Here's the workflow:

[image: Here's the workflow]

I am able to send the blob file, but I need to specify the name of the file always.
Is there any way I can get all the file contents dynamically without having to specify the name manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Get Blob Metadata using path` action to get the name of your file:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response! In Blob Content Using Path, do you specify just the path eg. /container/pictures/  or do you specify the name of the file as well? eg. /container/pictures/test.png ?

Comment: I use [List of Files Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jGvj.png) directly, because even if there are multiple blobs, they are executed separately. For example, if you upload three files at a time, they are executed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emX6j.png).

Comment: Hey @Frank, what if a new directory gets created every month in my container, with new files getting stored. And I need to dynamically get those contents, without having to manually change the path in my Logic app. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I thought about it for a while and saw that you posted a new post, so I just wrote the answer there, hoping to help you.

Comment: Thanks so much @Frank, for your response!! I'll check that out.