# Get monthly Azure billing invoice of Resource Group usage via email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-group

I want to get the monthly billing invoice of my Azure Resource Group usage sent to my mail instead of downloading it manually from the portal.
This can be possible at subscription level but can this be achieved at Resource group level?

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and help from Stack Overflow, I was able to achieve the requirement as mentioned in the question.

You have two options:-

1. Use the Schedule Export feature in Azure Cost Management.
2. Use the Azure Cost Management API to create export.

Once you've added scheduled the export, your invoice will be stored in your storage account. (You will need to add the storage account details in the export configuration)
I have used an Azure logic app to pick up the invoice file contents from my storage account and then send it via mail.

Check my post for further clarification -->
[Dynamically send blobs from azure storage account to email using azure logic apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377100/dynamically-send-blobs-from-azure-storage-account-to-email-using-azure-logic-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for this option,

To opt in, select your subscription from the Subscriptions blade. You have to opt in for each subscription you own. Select Send my invoice (you might not see this if you're not the account admin), and then select Opt In.

However the bill wont be at the resource group level details

Comment: Thats exactly my point. I needed it for the resource group level. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: There is no way to obtain if you have not followed the CAF , it can be done by tagging the resource group